# Copying files and getting Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ io_fread

Tags: ruby

I am trying to copy some files and calculating hashes, but for some files I get `Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ io_fread`

```
source = <file>
dir = <target dir>
sha_t = Digest::SHA256.file(source).hexdigest # <- Error
FileUtils.cp(source, dir)
```

So I obviously have no right to read the file. So I thought I could just check if I can read with:

```
File.readable?(source)
```

but this returns true.

How else do I check if I can read a file? I don't want to `begin ... rescue`

UPDATE:
I am using Windows and Ruby 2.1.3p242

I do not want to `chmod`, but just skip the file if it cannot be read.

Comment: I presume the error you're getting from Digest is Permission denied @ rb_sysopen...(Errno::EACCES). Is that correct?

Comment: @RedFred thanks for your effort. But I cannot reproduce this error (don't know why). Maybe I had some program open before that locked those files. I will update if I can reproduce error again.

Comment: no worries, I think you're right. Your code above should work, unless something else was locking the file.

Answer (score 1):

First, it would be really helpful if you described the OS and filesystem you were using.  For now, I'll assume you're using *NIX with an ext* filesystem.

A good way of checking files is using the built-in *Pathname* class, which works on both directories and files.

```
require 'pathname'
p = Pathname.new('/mypath/myfile.rb')
p.writable?
p.readable?
```

I suspect that in your case the problem can be solved by setting the right permission on the destination before copying to it:

```
Pathname.new(dir).chmod 755
FileUtils.cp(source, dir)
```

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right, the OS is quite important. And I am one of the few, that uses WIN as OS.